# How can I save a file i just created in the folder that I want in java?

Tags: java, file, path, jfilechooser

So I have this code where I can create a new file and write in it "head.txt", anyways I tried to make the `btnNewButton` open a JFileChooser where you can choose the folder where you want to save the new File. but it wont work. 
Here's my code:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            File filenew = new File (".");
            try {   
            String Src = "head.txt";
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
             chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
             String choosertitle = "nini";

             int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
             chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
                chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                File selectedfile ; 
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                   selectedfile =  chooser.getSelectedFile();

        String dest = selectedfile + File.separator + textField.getText()+".html";          
        File fileold = new File (Src); 
            FileInputStream fileinstr = new FileInputStream(fileold);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileinstr));
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (dest , true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            String aLine = null; 
                    while ((aLine = br.readLine())!=null){

                        out.write(aLine);
                        out.newLine();

                    }
            br.close ();
            out.close();
}

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        }
```

Here's my first code where i can create the file in my workspace :

```
try {   File filenew = new File (".");
        String Src = "head.txt";
        String dest = filenew.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + textField.getText()+".html";
        File fileold = new File (Src); 
        FileInputStream fileinstr = new FileInputStream(fileold);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileinstr));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (dest , true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        String aLine = null; 
                while ((aLine = br.readLine())!=null){

                    out.write(aLine);
                    out.newLine();
                }
        br.close ();
        out.close();


}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened the dialog before setting the properties:

```
int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

it should be:

```
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Comment: But now when I change the folder from my work space it wont reconize my file that I write from. `String Src = "head.txt";`

Comment: Is the head.txt in your working directory, or in the selected folder?

Comment: Then try to replace Src to "./head.txt"